# Trying to unlock & access a password locked Android cell phone that has screen damage on a small section so I can't input the last # of password

Tags: broken-screen, locked-out

I've tried going around the password with some of those programs they have advertised, where they claim it will eliminate the password requirement and get you right into your Android device. What I don't quite understand is what were they thinking of when in the procedures, one of the steps will involve changing the settings in the ***locked*** Android (e.g. Debugging must be on, or load this program onto the locked Android....)  Did someone actually go through some of these processes before releasing program? I mean, how are you supposed to get into the settings of a phone you're locked out of, or let alone, load a program or app onto the android you're trying to unlock? I wanna see that happen.

So anyway, I have an android cell phone, I dropped it, screen cracked and part of the screen has no capacity to input anything, it's like a dead area; screen works there, but no touch entry.

Is there any way of eliminating the passcode step, get into it, and load it up with mirror app to view and control the device? And, getting another device to recognize the locked device via USB wire connect.

Comment: Please check out the [broken screen Wiki page](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info). BTW: Posting a question that mainly consists of a rant is not very attractive for people who may post answers. In any way you should know that the Internet is full of crap and sharper who trying to get your money or data.

Comment: I don't know which programs you're talking about, but there's a grain of truth that if the device *already* has its USB Debugging enabled, then the program can possibly push and run the file to the Android device, even if the device is still locked behind the lockscreen.

Comment: as you already figured out all the progams advertising impossible thing. you simply can't by-pass screen lock

Comment: connect mouse via usb-otg adapter, unlock screen, connect bluethooth mouse/keyboard, connect pc via usb, enable usb-debugging and use scrcpy for remote control

Comment: or enable screen rotation, maybe no bluetooth required

Answer (score 0):

Things I have done:

1. Remote into the device
2. Connect a peripheral input device
3. Use ADB to send inputs (added bonus of being scriptable and/or AHK/Rainmeter combo)
4. Use the accessibility tools Assistant Menu or Universal Switches
5. Screen casting
6. Specific to Samsung Note series: the phone screen uses two separate touch digitizers.  If one is broken (e.g., touch), the other (in this case the magnetic induction digitizer) may still be functioning.